# TypeError: n is null in d3.min.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I used https://github.com/flrs/visavail to create a time-line chart.When I passed the dataset with only date ; I get the graph.But when I passed the time along with the date I get an error as  TypeError: n is null  in d3.min.js

I got an error while passing the following dataset:

```
var dataset = [{
    "measure": "Room Occupancy", // name of the data series, will become y-axis label
    "data": [
        ["2016-01-01 12:00:00", 1, "2016-01-01 13:00:00"], // 24-hour format
        ["2016-01-01 14:22:51", 1, "2016-01-01 16:14:12"],
        ["2016-01-01 19:20:05", 0, "2016-01-01 20:30:00"],
        ["2016-01-01 20:30:00", 1, "2016-01-01 22:00:00"]
    ]
}];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What message do you get if you include the uncompressed version ?

Comment: What version of D3 are you using?

Comment: @philipp Sorry I didn't understand what you meant by  Uncompressed version.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I use the following link <<script src="./vendors/d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>>  as mentioned in the example

Comment: Well, you have a script in that folder... what is its version?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado  version: "3.5.17"

Comment: Well, that's the correct version, and you're using a dataset described in their docs. So, unless you set up a working (running) example of the error, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: The following JSFiddle had an example that suits my requirement : http://jsfiddle.net/71jmupyd/24/

Answer (score -1):

I found the right way to get the time-line chart from the following JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/71jmupyd/24/

## Visavail.js Basic Example

This example demonstrates the basic use of Visavail.js.

```
<div id="chart">
<!-- Visavail.js chart will be placed here -->
</div>
```